# Predict a part of the input based of the output

Tags: machine-learning, math

I'm working on a fun project where I have a dataset of input and output data, both having a fixed size of characters.
I would like to predict a part of the input based on a known output as follows:

$$Input = A+B$$
$$Output = X+Y$$

**A**, **B**, **X**, **Y** are strings that will be concatenated and they have a fixed size

Knowing **A**, **X** and **Y**; I want to predict **B** *(even if it takes a lot of tries)*. The output is split in 2 because I don't really care what value **Y** has *(so maybe I can delete it, depending how is more easy)*.

Is it possible? I'm new to ML and AI and first I want to know if it possible before starting to work on the project *(I am time limited)*. And if it is possible then could you tell me what exactly to study/learn or how I can do it?

Comment: could you give us a more concrete example of these inputs/outputs? It would help to understand better the whole set up you described in the question. Also, if you're trying to predict something, that's the output by definition, and what you use to predict it is the input, they can be partially or literally the same thing, but "predicting an input" is not really an expression that makes sense. Not a criticism, but they way you put it make things a little bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, I can see how's confusing... I guess I can swap the input and output then. An example would be: "aaaaa" = "abcde" + predict_value (that would be X = A + B). So now I'll need to predict a part of the output.